# How to make efficient C++ jump table?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I'm beginner to C++ and I have implemented the following simple jump table, but was wondering if I'm doing it the right way. Is there anyway I can improve the following code?

The following code is using a dictionary (I'm from a C# background) to store functions' pointers.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void Zero() { printf("Zero\n"); }
void One() { printf("One\n"); }   
void Two() { printf("Two\n"); }
void Three() { printf("Three\n"); }

string prompt()
{
    printf("Enter number from 0 to 3 or q to quit:\n");
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    return line;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    unordered_map<string, void(*)()> map;

    map["0"] = Zero;
    map["1"] = One;
    map["2"] = Two;
    map["3"] = Three;

    while (true) {
        string c = prompt();
        if (c == "q") break;

        map[c]();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Efficient in what way?

Comment: How about when `m[c]` does not exist - i.e. user entered something that is not on the menu

Comment: Questions about improving working code are a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: The basic idea is fine, though the execution is defective in several unrelated ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much you can do to make your code "faster" without going for the switch solution which breaks the original idea of having an array of functions. If you only gonna use 'characters' such as '0' => '9', 'a' => 'z' you could dodge the memory allocation needed for the string, and you could also initialize your map with an initializer_list, and you could also make such array const static if that's viable.

Here goes my "optimized" code if it helps.

```
inline char prompt() //this function will probably 900% be inlined even if you don't specify the inlike keyword
{
    printf("Enter number from 0 to 3 or q to quit:\n");
    char v;
    while (!(std::cin >> v)); //Just to make sure we get valid input
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    static const std::unordered_map<char, void(*)()> mymap = 
    {
        { '0' , Zero },
        { '1' , One },
        { '2' , Two },
        { '3' , Three }
    };

    while(1)
    {
        auto it = mymap.find(prompt());

        // Without this check, your program will crash if input is invalid.
        if (it != mymap.end()) 
        {
            it->second();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was worried about the "string" and if I should use "char", you fixed it but why "inline"?

Comment: I explained it on my comment. It's not needed, but it's a way to let the people know that read your code that this function is expected to be inlined. These days the inline keyword doesn't do much, because the compiler always has the last word. __forceinline, has the name says, is different. that one actually forces the compiler to inline the function (but there's cases where the compiler can't inline the function for technical reasons) so a __forceinline function, may not be inlined in some cases.  __forceinline is MSVC specific btw.

Comment: How would that look if those functions took a parameter?

Answer (score 7):

How about a **switch** statement?

```
switch (c) {
   case 0:
      printf("Zero\n"); break;
   case 1:
      printf("One\n"); break;
   case 2:
      printf("Two\n"); break;
   case 3:
      printf("Three\n"); break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

Comment: In all likelihood this is the optimal solution. Certainly one the optimiser has had a chance to see it.

Comment: you should use  '0' instead of 0 in the switch statement.

Answer (score 4):

Pleas provide more details for your case of efficiency. Do you mean memory/cpu cycles/pass-through?
According to your code:

- it's not error prone (use `auto it = map.find(key);` function for searching and check output `it != map.end()` value, so no new elements will be created)
- it's good enough for string key type
- you case easily make more flexible by replacing function pointer with `std::function<void()>`

It terms of more low-level control you can you custom hash function and custom hash tables implementations. 
On some data it may be usefull to consider `std::map` or sorted `std::vector` as an option.

Answer (score 2):

As static lookup is **fast**, This will perform very good irrespective of compiler. Jump table differs from compiler to compiler. I would use following code, May be some people will object to this as `global` are bad. But before commenting, please evaluate this

```
string prompt()
{
     printf("Enter number from 0 to 3 or q to quit:\n");
     string line;
     getline(cin, line);

     return line;
}

enum Choice = {ZERO = 0, ONE, TWO, THREE};

static char *choice_str[] = {
     "Zero",
     "One",
     "Two",
     "Three"
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    while (true) {
        string c = prompt();
        if (c == "q") 
        {
            break;
         }
         else {
              assert(atoi(c) >= Choice::ZERO && atoi(c) <=Choice::THREE);
              printf("%s\n", choice_str[atoi(c)]);
         }
}
```